# Did this character "fool" Thanos and Dr Strange?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, **Dr. Strange** travels in time mentally to explore multiple outcomes, and only sees one positive outcome out of millions.

In the same film, **Thanos**' plan is to eradicate 50% of the universe's population and he carries on with it.

At the very end of *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, **Ant-Man** goes into the **Quantum realm** for an experiment. While **Ant-Man** is in this reality, *"a reality where all concepts of time and space become irrelevant"*, **Thanos** executes his plan, and 50% of the Universe's population disappears - including [some](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR3IQ.jpg) friends of **Ant-Man** leading the experiment.

Is it possible that Ant-Man being in the Quantum realm at this moment could mean that Dr. Strange couldn't perceive that he had survived in his mental evaluation of future outcomes - and therefore couldn't explore possible futures involving Ant-Man? Is it possible also that Ant-Man was spared because he was in the Quantum realm at that time, a reality that Thanos might not be able to impact even with the Infinity Stones?

Comment: Oohh! This gonna be interesting if kept open...

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't. It's clearly opinion-based. I suspect it **might** feed into *Avengers 4* but this won't be revealed for some time.

Comment: @Paulie_D nothing opinion-based in my question, since the characters of Ant-Man, Thanos and Dr Strange have been explored in hundreds of storylines and so many comics I have not read for the past 50 years, I'm assuming the "rules" have been set a long time ago. I'm just asking people who have read these comics if they can weigh in with quotes of the works, not asking happy speculators what they think. Also, nothing wrong with leaving the question until it gets answered more or less officially (I didn't flag to close the ones asking "when does ant man take place")

Comment: @MicroMachine It's still opinion based, because we have no information on how the infinity stones interact with the Quantum Realm in the MCU (Earth-199999). The best answer we can give is speculation based on what the stones have been observed to do, and how we've seen the quantum realm to function. 
If you want to open the question to answers that lie outside of the MCU, such as those seen in the main comic continuity (Earth-616) or the Ultimates universe (Earth-1610), then you may want to exclude the MCU tag.

Comment: I didn't realize MCU was different than Marvel comics, and also they're linked right? Also how can it be an opinion if they already shot the second part of Avengers infinity Wars, and they're gonna release it pretty soon (in less than a year)? It's only a matter of weeks now before we have a trailer. Like I said, I don't downvote questions people ask about a movie that I've seen that has not been released where they live. And like you said maybe there are hints and clues all over the place in these films I didn't catch.

Comment: I'm not down-voting, I think the question itself is quite interesting, and one of the reasons why I personally don't agree with the "future works policy" on other stack sites. However it is impossible to definitively answer at the present time. MCU already differs from the main comic universe in several ways, and pulls in some elements from the Ultimates universe as well, so any comic sourced answer is liable to be proved incorrect when the future films emerge, and until Avengers 4 is released, we cannot say for certain how the stones will interact with the quantum realm there.

Comment: Thank you. "What we know" is definitely subjective, depending on what day it is, and subject to change any minute and that's also why I asked the question.

Comment: @MicroMachine SF&F has dug up an official answer, Word of God says it's just luck and that he could have been snapped. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191511/was-ant-man-spared-because-of-his-location

Comment: @AAlig why was my question shut down, but this guy's question is thriving?

Comment: I can't speak for the communities, but it looks like that one was almost close voted for "future works" as well, until someone unearthed the tweet that made it answerable (which has since been deleted).

Comment: Official answer: https://imgur.com/OaI1Qto - although if I understand correctly, time passing at a different rate in the Quantum Realm would mean that the snap occurs at a different time in the quantum realm?

Answer (score 8):

**We can't know for certain.**

Disclaimers:

1. There is nothing to suggest that the Quantum Realm shown in Ant-Man and Wasp behaves like it's comic book counterpart, the [microverse](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Microverse).
2. Current comic continuity has not (to the best of my knowledge) touched on how the Soul Gems (Comic equivalent to Infinity Stones in the MCU) interact with the Microverse.
3. The MCU has shown no evidence for the Quantum Realm being affected or unaffected by the infinity stones.

I will try to answer the questions above as logically as possible, but be forewarned that this is all speculation, as no hard information on the topic is available.

> Is it possible that Ant-Man being in the Quantum realm at this moment
>   could mean that Dr. Strange couldn't perceive that he had survived in
>   his mental evaluation of future outcomes - and therefore couldn't
>   explore possible futures involving Ant-Man?

Dr. Strange is not "theorizing" or running a simulation of what will happen. He is using the Time Stone to view ~all~ Fourteen million, six hundred and five of the possible timelines:

> I went forward in time. To view alternate futures. To see all the possible outcomes of the coming conflict.

Because he was actually traveling through time, he was not perceiving whether he survived or did not. It is possible that he was temporarily unaware that Lang survived, due to Lang being unreachable, but he saw all the futures that could happen, including those that have Lang joining the fight (assuming he does join the fight in any of the alternate futures).

> Is it possible also that Ant-Man was spared because he was in the
>   Quantum realm at that time, a reality that Thanos might not be able to
>   impact even with the Infinity Stones?

I see nothing to indicate that the quantum realm would be beyond Thanos' power to impact, except for this quote by Hank Pym:

> ...a reality where all concepts of time and space become irrelevant as
>   you shrink for all eternity

However, we've already seen an MCU example of the Infinity Stones (specifically the Time Stone) functioning in a "reality without the concept of time and space" when Strange created a time loop within Dormamu's realm. If the Time stone can still affect a realm beyond time and beyond space, we have no evidence to assume that the other stones would be unable to affect it.

Comment: @MicroMachine Thanks, I tried to keep this answer as MCU-centric as possible. The guys over at Scifi&Fantasy may have a better answer in terms of how the interaction between them would work out in the comic continuity, if you wanted to ask there. I'm a pretty avid fan/reader, but they put me to shame.

Comment: "Fourteen million, six hundred and five" seems small when talking about _all possible timelines_